# React dynamically rendering component (object assign vs. function return)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've hit a brick wall here, meaning I can't fully figure out why the next two versions of code behave so differently.

In the first version, when I'm initialising a `this.childComponent = (<ChildComp />)`, its props do not seem to update when I change the `Parent`'s state (via `setState()`). This happens even though the `setState()` is actually called, and the `Parent`'s state is updated.

In the second version, when I'm actually initialising a function that returns the component (`this.childComponent = () => {return (<ChildComp />)}`), everything works like a charm, props are updated.
I am using the second version (since it works), but I'd like to understand why this works and the first one doesn't.

Here's the child component:

```
class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick=(this.props.setValue())>
        {this.props.value}
      </button>
    )
  }
}
```

I have the next two versions of the parent component:

**1.**

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      value: 1
    }
    this.childComponent = (
      <Child value={this.state.value} 
      setValue={() => this.setValue()}/>
    )
  }
  setValue() {
    this.setState({value: 2})
  }
  render () {
    return ( {this.childComponent} )
  }  
}
```

**2.**  (the `this.childComponent` is now a function that returns the react Element)

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      value: 1
    }
    this.childComponent = () => {
      return (
        <Child value={this.state.value} 
        setValue={() => this.setValue()}/>
      )
    }
  }
  setValue() {
    this.setState({value: 2})
  }
  render () {
    return ( {this.childComponent()} )
  }   
}
```

I've tried to simplify the code so my issue is easier to understand.

Thank you in advance

Comment: In your first (broken) version the child component is defined statically and never changed again.

Comment: You don't have a return in the first case `render () {
    return {this.childComponent}
  } ` may work otherwise the child component is static

Comment: Got it, thanks for the explanations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React uses a strategy called [reconciliation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html) to efficiently update the DOM every time there's a change in its internal state. Typically, this happens after a `setState` call.

In your first example, the `render` method inside the `Parent` component always returns the same `Child` component, as it's created only once in the `constructor`. Because of this, the reconciliation algorithm doesn't find any changes since there aren't any.

I'd like to point out that `<Child value={this.state.value} setValue={() => this.setValue()}/>` is just syntactic sugar for `React.createElement(Child, {value: this.state.value, setValue: () => this.setValue()}, null)`. [createElement](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#createelement) simply returns an object.

In your second example, with every `render` call, you're calling `childComponent` which in turns create a new `Child` component.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a return in the first case since

```
this.childComponent = (
  <Child value={this.state.value} 
  setValue={() => this.setValue()}/>
)
```

was defined in the constructor which is  executed only once and is a static value now.

whereas it  will work as it is a function that is executed everytime it is called.

If you want to go by the first method, define the childcomponent in the render rather than the constructor since render is called on every change. Your code also had a lot of mistakes. See the working snippet below

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      value: 1
    }
   
  }
  setValue() {
    this.setState({value: 2})
  }
  render () {
      const childComponent = (
      <Child value={this.state.value} 
      setValue={() => this.setValue()}/>
    )
    return ( <div>{childComponent}</div> )
  }  
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.props.setValue}>
        {this.props.value}
      </button>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Added an explanation and a working snippet with the first method